# hierarchyid for child's parents table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm back with next question: How can I build a table with hierarchical data when  I know two parents (id_mother and id_father). Is like that?
CREATE TABLE dbo.children

(

```
[Id] hierarchyid not null primary key,

[Name] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
```

)

GO
But how to proper insert values in this tabel and how it works?

Comment: If you already know that you will have a mother and father structure, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the struture that you're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE hierarchy
(id INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
father_id INTEGER,
mother_id INTEGER,
Name NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

Comment: After a closer look I realized that you're right. Since I know the parents I do not have to create the hierarchy table. I just have to find the most effective method to manipulate data